# ionic framework: errors when trying running "ionic upload" command

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, browser, command-line-interface, polyfills

I'm trying to upload my Ionic project, so that I could view it in Ionic View, but I'm getting the following errors while running the "ionic upload" command: https://i.stack.imgur.com/suQ5H.png. The path to the project is partially blurred due to it containing my full name which I'm not comfortable sharing, but that is the only thing which is blurred. Every other error etc is shown on the picture.

I tried running the command straight after editing the project. I already have an Ionic View account linked with the CLI. The app works fine while running it in the browser with "ionic serve --lab".

Does anyone know what the issue might be here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this. To anyone who is having the same problem, run this in the project main directory:

```
npm install promise-polyfill --save-exact
```